# Delphi ActionMainMenuBar Category Position

Tags: delphi

I'm creating **ActionMainMenuBar with Categories** dynamically and everything working fine BUT as ActionMainMenuBar **align is alBottom** (like second option menu just bottom) when press button with categories they show up below ActionMainMenuBar. It will always try to show them below if enough space.
Is there any way to set categories position to be above or to do trick like "not enough space below" and it will automatically show category menu above

[image: Picture with issue]

RAD Studio 10.1,VCL
P.S. the same thing is with ToolBar etc

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. Code is in `TCustomActionPopupMenu.PositionPopup` in "actnmenus.pas". No questions asked. Looks reasonable to me as they simulate menus. I don't know, however, if you are able to register your own popup class. Probably would be more work then you'd like even if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `TCustomActionPopupMenu.PositionPopup` in unit `Vcl.ActnMenus` that is responsible for positioning the menu as the comment below your question points out. You can customize popup menu class for your main menu using `OnGetPopupClass` event. Or you can create your own action bar style by subclassing any existing style and it's not that much work at all. Another option would be to hook into method `TCustomActionPopupMenu.PositionPopup` and "fix" its behaviour according to your needs.

I'm going to expand on all three approaches, but let's start with what they have in common - amendment of method `PositionPopup`. It takes two arguments:

1. `AnOwner: TCustomActionBar` - the action bar (main menu in your case) that is displaying the popup menu
2. `ParentItem: TCustomActionControl` - an item within the action bar that invoked the popup menu.

Particularly we're only interested when `AnOwner` is aligned to the bottom and `ParentItem` is `TCustomMenuButton` (top-level main menu item). The idea is to let `PositionPopup` to calculate menu bounds rectangle and then move it up by the the height of itself plus `ParentItem.Height`. We would do this only when the originally calculated position is below `ParentItem` and there's enough space above it.

### Option 1: Custom Popup Class

You can customize popup menu class using event [`OnGetPopupClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar.OnGetPopupClass) of 
 `TActionMainMenuBar`:

```
type
  TMyThemedPopupMenu = class(TThemedPopupMenu)
  protected
    procedure PositionPopup(AnOwner: TCustomActionBar; ParentItem: TCustomActionControl); override;
  end;

procedure TMyThemedPopupMenu.PositionPopup(AnOwner: TCustomActionBar; ParentItem: TCustomActionControl);
var
  ParentItemPosition: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(AnOwner) and (AnOwner.Align = alBottom) and
     Assigned(ParentItem) and (ParentItem is TCustomMenuButton) then
  begin
    ParentItemPosition := ParentItem.ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
    if (ParentItemPosition.Y < Top) and (0 <= Top - Height - ParentItem.Height) then
      Top := Top - Height - ParentItem.Height;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ActionMainMenuBar1GetPopupClass(Sender: TObject;
  var PopupClass: TCustomPopupClass);
begin
  if PopupClass = TThemedPopupMenu then
    PopupClass := TMyThemedPopupMenu;
end;
```

Note that this implementation replaces popup class with your custom class only if the original class was `TThemedPopupMenu`. This happens when you didn't change style of action manager to Standard, XP or another custom style and when the platform the application is running on supports themes. But you can easily extend it to support `TStandardMenuPopup` and `TXPStylePopupMenu`.

### Option 2: Custom Action Bar Style

I will subclass [`TPlatformDefaultStyleActionBars`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls.TPlatformDefaultStyleActionBars), because it's the default style. As per above it can either create standard style, XP style or themed style action controls based on platform. I will again only focus on themed action controls. This option uses the implementation of `TMyThemedPopupMenu` from option #1.

```
type
  TMyActionBarStyle = class(TPlatformDefaultStyleActionBars)
  public
    function GetPopupClass(ActionBar: TCustomActionBar): TCustomPopupClass; override;
  end;

var
  MyActionBarStyle: TMyActionBarStyle;

function TMyActionBarStyle.GetPopupClass(ActionBar: TCustomActionBar): TCustomPopupClass;
begin
  Result := inherited GetPopupClass(ActionBar);
  if Result = TThemedPopupMenu then
    Result := TMyThemedPopupMenu;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActionManager1.Style := MyActionBarStyle;
end;

{ ... }

initialization
  MyActionBarStyle := TMyActionBarStyle.Create;
finalization
  MyActionBarStyle.Free;
end.
```

Notice that I'm setting the style at runtime in `FormCreate`, but you can as well put the style into a package and register it via [`RegisterActnBarStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.ActnMenus.RegisterActnBarStyle). That would allow you to select style of action manager in design-time.

### Option 3: Hooking TCustomActionPopupMenu.PositionPopup

If you don't want to worry about various styles, you can hook directly into `TCustomActionPopupMenu.PositionPopup` using e.g. [Delphi Detours Library](https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/DDetours). This will affect all styles, because all of their popup menu implementations inherit from `TCustomActionPopupMenu`.

```
uses System.Types, DDetours, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ActnMan, Vcl.ActnMenus, Vcl.ActnPopup;

type
  TCustomActionPopupMenuAccess = class(TCustomActionPopupMenu);

var
  TrampolinePositionPopup: procedure(const Self; AnOwner: TCustomActionBar;
    ParentItem: TCustomActionControl);

procedure PositionPopupHooked(const Self; AnOwner: TCustomActionBar;
  ParentItem: TCustomActionControl);
var
  PopupMenu: TCustomActionPopupMenu;
  ParentItemPosition: TPoint;
begin
  TrampolinePositionPopup(Self, AnOwner, ParentItem);
  if Assigned(AnOwner) and (AnOwner.Align = alBottom) and
     Assigned(ParentItem) and (ParentItem is TCustomMenuButton) then
  begin
    PopupMenu := TCustomActionPopupMenu(@Self);
    ParentItemPosition := ParentItem.ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
    if (ParentItemPosition.Y < PopupMenu.Top) and (0 <= PopupMenu.Top - PopupMenu.Height - ParentItem.Height) then
      PopupMenu.Top := PopupMenu.Top - PopupMenu.Height - ParentItem.Height;
  end;
end;

initialization
  TrampolinePositionPopup := InterceptCreate(
    @TCustomActionPopupMenuAccess.PositionPopup, @PositionPopupHooked);
finalization
  InterceptRemove(@TrampolinePositionPopup);
end.
```

Comment: Thank you Peter.  Option 1 works perfectly for me but I will also try option 2 and 3 as they are good for learning and deeper understanding all of this. Regards... TK

Comment: Option #1 is sutiable for single behaviour adjustment. With option #2 you can create reusable style across one or more applications. Option #3 provides a way to adjust action controls' behaviour not taking style into account.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set dynamic padding and/or Margin (down) value.

Comment: Can you provide more detail and be more specific? What you've written doesn't provide much in the way of information. There's no such thing as a `Down` value for TMargin or TPadding.

Comment: I can't write a full response because I don't have the code. Theoretically, the control has a 'dynamic' height value. From the sum of the height of the sub-controls within the control, frame, etc. you can calculate the height value of the free space below. It is possible to enter a lower margin or a lower padding value close to this value.

If the appearance is distorted, a second way is to add a fake button with the calculated height.